# R - how to print only the field containing a string match

Tags: r, loops, subset

Using the following command: `kable(head(table), format = "markdown")`

I generated the following `table`:

```
|V1             |V2                    |V3                   |V4                  |V5                   |V6                    |V7                   |V8                    |V9            |V10              |
|:--------------|:---------------------|:--------------------|:-------------------|:--------------------|:---------------------|:--------------------|:---------------------|:-------------|:----------------|
|LdBPK_271870.1 |plasma membrane: 0.52 |Golgi apparatus: 0.2 |ER: 0.09            |extracellular: 0.08  |mitochondrial: 0.07   |cytoplasmic: 0.02    |lysosomal: 0.01       |nuclear: 0.01 |peroxisomal: 0.0 |
|LdBPK_220004.1 |nuclear: 0.56         |cytoplasmic: 0.42    |mitochondrial: 0.01 |peroxisomal: 0.0     |Golgi apparatus: 0.0  |plasma membrane: 0.0 |extracellular: 0.0    |ER: 0.0       |lysosomal: 0.0   |
|LdBPK_020440.1 |cytoplasmic: 0.54     |nuclear: 0.45        |mitochondrial: 0.0  |Golgi apparatus: 0.0 |peroxisomal: 0.0      |plasma membrane: 0.0 |extracellular: 0.0    |ER: 0.0       |lysosomal: 0.0   |
|LdBPK_313080.1 |nuclear: 0.6          |cytoplasmic: 0.29    |mitochondrial: 0.06 |peroxisomal: 0.02    |Golgi apparatus: 0.01 |extracellular: 0.01  |plasma membrane: 0.01 |ER: 0.0       |lysosomal: 0.0   |
|LdBPK_201720.1 |cytoplasmic: 0.89     |nuclear: 0.06        |mitochondrial: 0.02 |peroxisomal: 0.01    |Golgi apparatus: 0.01 |extracellular: 0.0   |plasma membrane: 0.0  |ER: 0.0       |lysosomal: 0.0   |
|LdBPK_070130.1 |cytoplasmic: 0.61     |nuclear: 0.32        |peroxisomal: 0.05   |mitochondrial: 0.02  |Golgi apparatus: 0.0  |plasma membrane: 0.0 |extracellular: 0.0    |ER: 0.0       |lysosomal: 0.0   |
```

In my `table` I want to loop over each line and:

1. print the column V1
2. Loop over each line and print only the field that matches the string I am after

For example, say I am after the string "nuclear" the code would do the following.

1. On the first line, print the field under column V1 (LdBPK_271870.1) and then
2. scan from columns V2 to V10 and print only the whole field (i.e. including the values after the string "nuclear") that matches the string "nuclear".
3. repeat this to all lines of my table.

In that case, considering my `table` the code would, on the first line, print the fields under V1 and V9. On the second line, the code would print me the fields under V1 and V2. On the third it would print me, the field under V1 and V3. Until it reaches the end of my table. The output would then be a table of two columns: the first one identical to V1 and the second one would only contain the string "nuclear" and the value that follows for each line.

I cannot subset my data using square brackets because the string I am after can be under any of the columns V2 to V10.

Comment: Why does the string being in any of the columns mean you can't subset the square brackets? Imagine a nested for loop that checks each element to see whether the [i,j] element contains the string"nuclear". If yes, do X. If no, pass.

Comment: I mean without the use of any loops...

Comment: In your question you said you wanted to loop.

Comment: Absolutely I can make use of loops. What I am trying to say is that sub-seting with square brackets (without the help of any loops) will not make the job.

Comment: Does my answer below print what you are interested in?

Comment: I did get a vector called row with 70L, although no table.

Comment: I've edited the answer. I had a typo. You should use grepl instead of %in%. However, this will not return a "table". It will print the relevant columns for each row, which is what you asked for. It's not clear to me what you mean otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the fastest approach (because it's recreating a vector every iteration), but you could try something like this. This would print out for each row the first column (V1) and whichever columns contain your desired string. If a column doesn't have your desired string, it wouldn't print out the V1 value (but you didn't indicate that is an issue). If you know beforehand that the desired string will only appear in one column, you can speed up this loop by initializing the "relevant" vector as length 1 and then inputting the column value.

```
for(row in 1:nrow(table)) {
    relevant = c()
    for(col in 1:ncol(table)) {
        if(grepl("your_string", table[row, col])) {
            relevant <- c(relevant, col)
        }

    }
    if(length(relevant) > 0) {
        print(paste(table[row, 1], table[row, relevant]))
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, now is working perfectly and doing exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BCArg You are very welcome! Please accept this answer in case someone has the same question in the future and sees this post

Comment: But even better would be the output as a table of two columns, it is absolutely fine this way though. I probably can bind this vector to the first column of my original table using cbind

Comment: @BCArg If you want to add to a dataframe instead of printing the rows out, you could create an empty dataframe before the loop and then use "rbind" to add a row to the dataframe each iteration (instead of printing)